# why passing console=ttyS1 to init rather than kernel also works?

Tags: kernel, grub, console

I am studying serial console of Linux(Ubuntu Bionic, kernel 4.20).

In grub.cfg's kernel command line, simply appending `console=ttyS1` works well:

```
other kernel options ...... console=ttyS1
```

, but I found that Ubuntu MAAS has a configuration which eventually generates following kernel command line:

```
other kernel options ...... --- console=ttyS1
```

, the difference is that it prepend a `---` to `console=ttyS1`,

It also works well, I could see the kernel output(dmesg) of the OS, I could not see any difference of effects of above two ways.

However, according to [linux kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html),

> Everything after “–” is passed as an argument to init

So my question is, why passing `console=ttyS1` to `init` also works like passing to `kernel`?

Comment: Our question is why do you think that `--` is the same as `---`?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552950/triple-dash-on-linux-kernel-command-line-switches/11943253

Comment: @JdeBP thank you so much. Inspired by your answer, I found that the `--- console=ttyS1` 
 was actually passed to `kernel`, I have confirmed it by `cat /proc/cmdline`.

Comment: thank you all for your time. I think you can close this question.

Comment: It's actually a question, about the question, in what is known as a _question comment_.  Answers appear under an "Answers" heading, which the confusing WWW UI hides if there aren't any.

Comment: @JdeBP "Our question is why do you think that -- is the same as ---?",  the https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html just mentions a single dash, it makes me thing that it is just an inaccurate description, maybe it just means start with a single dash.  After your answer, I searched for other help document, found that it is clear that it should be double dash `--`,  https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.rst